# How can I open a txt file with vim by using shortcut [By using AutoHotKey]

Tags: vim, autohotkey

I'm using vim to open file quite frequently in **windows**.

Normally, open the file by `right-click file` -> select `Edit with Vim`. I'd like to open the file more quickly.

I've tried by using this way: `right-click file` -> `press` <kbd>v</kbd>(because press <kbd>v</kbd> would auto select the context-menu *Edit with Vim*). But, there are two context menu by using `&v` way (*Edit with Vim* and *Restore previous versions*).

Then, I want to using **Autohotkey** help to do it. But there are something wrong with my scripts:

```
!e::
  ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  Sendinput ^c
  While(!Clipboard)
  {
    ClipWait,0.1,1
    If A_Index > %MaxTimeWait%
      Break
  }
  Select = %Clipboard%
  IsFile := DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable","int",15)
  Clipboard := ClipSaved
  ClipSaved =
  If IsFile
  {
    Run, "C:\Marslo\MyProgramFiles\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%Select"
  }
Return
```

Error is:[image: ahk]

What should I do can open file by using: `Select file` -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The problem is exactly what the message says. When using a variable in a string, you need to **enclose** it in percent signs: `Run, "C:\Marslo\MyProgramFiles\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%Select%"`

Comment: If the files you are opening in gVim share a common extension you could set gVim as the default handler for those file types, so you wouldn't need to play with Autohotkey.

Comment: Hi @mMontu, Vim cannot be all file's default-opening-programme. For example, python, I using vim to edit it. But I need python.exe to be the default-openning-progamme.

Comment: @MCL you are right! My fault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
!e::
  ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  Sendinput ^c
  While(!Clipboard)
  {
    ClipWait,0.1,1
    If A_Index > %MaxTimeWait%
      Break
  }
  Select := Clipboard
  IsFile := DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable","int",15)
  Clipboard := ClipSaved
  ClipSaved =
  If IsFile
  {
    Run, "C:\Marslo\MyProgramFiles\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe %Select%"
  }
Return
```

1. I corrected your `Run` command. `Select` variable should be enclosed
   with `%`, like this `%Select%` as suggested by **MCL**.
2. I replaced `Select = %Clipboard%` with `Select := Clipboard`. I
   always try to use `:=` instead of `=`.

Does my code works for you?

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Hi @vasili111, Thanks for you and @MCL kindly reminding, I've corrected the `Run, "C:\Marslo\MyProgramFiles\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%Select"` to `Run, "C:\Marslo\MyProgramFiles\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%Select%"`(Add `%` for enclose the Select), and everything's fine! It works! Thanks!!